# Caseinsensitive Parameter Expansion

Tags: bash

my problem is, I try to strip a string at a start of a variable. I have done `shopt -s exglob` to get extended pattern matching.

```
    a="HelloDolly"
    echo "${a#[A-Z]+([a-z])}"
```

I thought that `+([a-z])` mean as much lower case letter as possible. And that `[A-Z]+([a-z])` should match `Hello`

should return Dolly but I get `lloDolly` back. If give `/` instead `#` a try

```
    echo "${a/[A-Z]+([a-z])}"
```

I get back nothing. Looks like the Parameter Expansions is caseinsensitive.

Thanks everybody who could give me an hint.

Comment: `echo "${a/[A-Z]+([a-z])}"` should work for you, I get `Dolly` as output.

Answer (score 1):

Using a single #, you get the shortest possible match. "He" is the shortest possible match of one uppercase letter and one or more lowercase letters. Switch to double # to get the longest possible match "Hello"

```
echo "${a##[A-Z]+([a-z])}"
```

To avoid issues with locale-based interpretation of character ranges, use character classes instead:

```
echo "${a##[[:upper:]]+([[:lower:]])}"
```

Comment: it gives empty string for me. `extglob` is on.

Comment: [This page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/571958) may be relevant. To be safe, use character classes instead of ranges, as shown in the updated answer.

Comment: oh neat you have two accounts

Comment: Thanks for your hint. The solution with `##` worked as expected. But could you please give some more details about the problem with the _locale-based interpretation of character ranges_. Because `${a/[[:upper:]]+([[:lower:]])}` worked as expected and `${a/[A-Z]+([a-z])}` not. How could I see how which characters are in a character range?

Comment: My (incomplete) understanding is that the characters included in `[a-z]` depend on the sort order of the current locale. It's not a strict sequence of ASCII code points, so if the current locale uses dictionary sort order, it would include `aAbB...zZ`, not just `a...z`.